# Draw grid lines in vtkXYPlotActor

Tags: c++, vtk

I want to show the grid lines in a graph created using vtkXYPlotActor.
Can you suggest me how?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `vtkXYPlotActor` class it is difficult modify the underlying (generated) plot data and settings.

You are better off using the `vtkChartXY` class , which allows this easily using something like

```
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkChartXY> chart =    vtkSmartPointer<vtkChartXY>::New();
  chart->GetAxis(0)->SetGridVisible(true);
  chart->GetAxis(0)->SetGridVisible(true);
```

If you don't have access to the `vtkChartXY` class you have two options both of which are more work than upgrading.

1. Attempt to make your own version of `vtkXYPlotActor` that uses
   `vtkAxisActor` instead of  `vtkAxisActor2D`, either through
   subclassing or from creating from scratch. 
   `vtkAxisActor` has the 2 relevant modifiers for gridlines `vtkAxisActor::SetDrawGridlines` and `vtkAxisActor::SetGridlinesProperty`, whilst `vtkAxisActor2D` doesn't have these.
   This is non trivial.
2. Make a 3D plot and move the camera so the plot looks like it is 2D.

Further VTK references include

- [VTK Plotting Examples](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx#Plotting)
- [vtkChartXY Class Reference](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkChartXY.html)
- [vtkXYPlotActor Class Reference](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkXYPlotActor.html)

Comment: Thanks Appleman1234. I am using vtk 5.4 version, it does not support this vtkChartXY. I was looking for a way to do it within this version. Any idea?